# Something like an incomplete gamma function

Tags: calculus, number-theory

I want to compute $\int_0^z t^{-b}e^t \,dt$ where $b>0$ by using incomplete gamma function.
Can I rewrite my integral as a form of the incomplete gamma function?

Answer (score 1):

Making the change of variables $t=-u$, we have
$$ \int_0^z t^{-b}e^t \,dt = -\int_{0}^{-z} (-u)^{-b}e^{-u} \,du=(-1)^{-b+1}\int_{0}^{-z} t^{-b}e^{-u} \,du=(-1)^{1-b}\gamma(1-b,-z), $$

where [$\gamma(s,x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) is the lower incomplete gamma function.